# How to get dynamic coupon code in Subscription Newsletter template in Magento1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, newsletter, coupon-codes

I have created a newsletter template for giving 20% discount to customers by a dynamic coupon code. I created a shopping cart price rule with dynamic coupon code but I am unable to fetch that coupon code in Newsletter template.

How to get dynamic coupon code in newsletter email ?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this I think is to create a system configuration to contain  the discount code value and then reference the value in the email template.

1. Create system config for the coupon you will be showing (select type) - You should create a module, I won't go into the details as you can easily find this elsewhere
2. Create the source model  for populating the select(ideally active
   coupons) - something like this

`class Phil_TransactionalEmails_Model_System_Config_Source_Couponcodes {

```
protected $_options;
public function toOptionArray(){
    $rulesCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('salesrule/rule_collection')->load();

    if (!$this->_options) {
        $this->_options = array();
        foreach ($rulesCollection as $item) {

            if ($item->getIsActive() == 1 && $item->getData('code') != null) {
                $_couponCode = Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($item->getData('code'));
                $_couponCodeName = Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($item->getData('name'));

                $this->_options[] = array(
                    'value' => $_couponCode,
                    'label' => $_couponCode . ' - ' . $_couponCodeName
                );
            }

        }
    }
    // Sort alphabetical
    usort($this->_options, function ($a, $b) {
        return strcmp($a['value'], $b['value']);
    });

    return $this->_options;

}
```

}
`

Apologies for the formatting, cant seem to get it to work properly.

3. Set up the permissions to allow  the system config to be used in
   emails  System > Permissions > Variables
4. Reference the code in email template

`{{config path='yourconfigpath'}}`

If you don't care about it being manageable you can probably just create a variable directive and query the coupon by id for your specific coupon value.